# Read macros in Scheme

Tags: scheme

In Common Lisp, there are "read macros" that can be used to parse syntax to Lisp code.

1. Is it possible/how to implement it in pure Scheme?
2. Which and how implementations support this?

Comment: Not pure Scheme, but Racket has them: http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Reader_Extension.html

Comment: Since a reader macro would require hooks into your parser, it probably would need to be implemented by the Scheme that you are using. IE, you probably cannot implement it in pure scheme unless you are building your own parser.

Answer (score 3):

The only semi-portable way that comes to mind is via [SRFI-10](http://srfi.schemers.org/srfi-10/srfi-10.html)'s limited form of reader macros. These have to start with a sharp sign and a comma, and then a list expression which starts with a symbol which identifies the read-time constructor.

CHICKEN also provides support for using [arbitrary characters](http://wiki.call-cc.org/man/4/Unit%20library#reader-extensions) as reader macro hooks.

Comment: sounds like [data readers](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/*data-readers*) in Clojure, which otherwise lacks a user-accessible reader macro system.